# How to inactive elements behind sliding drawer content in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have a `ListView` with clickable items. Then I have a sliding drawer with content containing nothing but 50% transparent black background which fills parent in both directions.

The issue is when I click on the sliding drawer content layer (anywhere in black background) it triggers click on listview item which is *beneath* it.

How do I make so that anything behind sliding drawer content layout is inactive?

*(I tried setting clickable to false on the content layout and it didn't help)*

Comment: I think you should set clickable state of your sliding drawer's content layout to true.

Comment: Works perfectly! Add it as the answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set clickable state of your sliding drawer's content layout to `true`.